# In Flash CS 5 Publish settings - New flash player is not in drop down options

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flash

My newest version of Flash Player is 11.2. However my project still compiles under 10 & 10.1 and there is no option to switch it to 11.2.  What do I need to do to get that option? Do I need to install something?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just because you have the *player* doesn't mean that you have the proper tools to *compile* for flash 11

Adobe has [some information](http://blogs.adobe.com/rgalvan/2011/11/adding-fp11-support-to-flash-pro-cs5-and-cs5-5.html) that is likely to help you. It was also the first result on google for "flash 11 support cs5"